# Why can't I import the package that I just installed?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I recently started learning flutter/dart and I have a Problem that i couldn't solve. I've read in the official flutter documentation that you have to follow these three steps to install a package in flutter:

1. Add the package (in my case: 'english_words: ^3.1.5') to the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file.
2. Run the 'flutter pub get' command to include the package to the '.packages' file.
3. Add import 'yourpackagename' (in my case: 'package:english_words/english_words.dart') to the main.dart file.

My problem is though that VS marks it as an error if I try to do step 3: *Target of the URI doesn't exist*

Any ideas what I could do? I've installed the *flutter* and *dart* extensions for VS Code and also tried to restart the program but nothing worked.

Comment: Sometimes I run flutter clean and flutter pub get then I have to restart ide in order to import package

Comment: Sometimes depending on the speed of your computer, it can take the vscode flutter extension a while before it recognizes that you've installed a package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try running

```
flutter clean
```

if it is still not working, run:

```
flutter clean pub cache
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while doing the Google codelab, the solution for me was to open a terminal in VS Code and run the command `flutter pub get` and then try importing the pack again.